# How can I get data from another ativity by non-Activity class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-softkeyboard

I have a soft-keyboard that dose not expands activity it has one button when I click on that I intent another app perfectly but when I want to get respond from that app which extends activity and has a button, the problem is that when I click that button it gets back to my first app but my first app could not get-intent from that.
here is my some part of my soft-keyboard:

```
  public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
   if (primaryCode == LatinKeyboardView.KEYCODE_11) // username_paste_button
    {
        handle_username_paste(); // handle username_paste_button
    }

}
private void handle_username_paste() { // handle username_paste_button
   try {
               // url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlTextEdit);
                String text ="google.com";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
                i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("fake.domain.examplesta");
                i.putExtra("URL", text);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startActivity(i);
               // startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "App Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("OTP");
}
```

have any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would call `startActivityForResult(i, 1)` to start an activity and when you are done with that activity you call:

`setResult(RESULT_OK)
finish()`

Now the thing is, in order to receive the results you need the method `startActivityForResult()` which is only available from a class which extends the Activity class. You have not given much information as to what the 'soft-keyboard' class is doing or used exactly, but the only advice I can give is to restructure your class to be driven from Activities.

Comment: well my class does not extents Activity, that is the problem and could not extent it neither.

Comment: Create a new Activitiy class and work from there? Why can't you extend it?